# First Child doesnt work? Syntax Error?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
.social-share li: first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

the above doesn't work?
First Child doesn't work? Syntax Error?

Comment: There should be no space after the colon... `li:first-child`

Comment: do not leave space between your li: and first-child

Comment: Yes worked. pleaese update the asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space before `:first-child` ...!

```css
.social-share li:first-child {background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<ul class="social-share">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this demo:

```css
.social-share li:first-child{background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="social-share">

<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no space bar between `li:` & `first child`
It should be like

```
.social-share li:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```